# Cucumber scenario outline when the input itself is a table

Tags: cucumber, bdd

So imagine a feature being developed is describing how to process tables or CSV/Excel files. The first approach might be to simply use Scenarios and data tables

```
Feature: Calculate from CSVs
  Scenario: sum column C filtered by A
    Given the CSV file:
     | A | B     | C |
     | a | true  | 9 |
     | e | false | 8 |
     | a | false | 5 |
    When I calculate sum filtered by value in A being "a"
    Then the answer is 14

  Scenario: sum column C sum by A
    Given the CSV file:
      | A | B     | C |
      | a | true  | 9 |
      | e | false | 8 |
      | a | false | 5 |
    When I calculate sum of C grouped by A values
    Then the answer table is:
      | A | C  |
      | a | 14 |
      | e | 8  |
```

Awkardly Intellij plugin seems to have a hard time with data tables in general so no example here, but I'm pretty sure that can be converted to code (Java in my case).
However what would be nice would be to use scenario outline and examples to cover a wider set. Of course this is **invalid** gherkin but essentially nest multiline tables into an example block somehow, perhaps with different column delimiters

```
  Scenario Outline:
    Given input csv <example>
    When I use filter <filter> on A
    Then I get table <output>
    Examples:
      | example   | filter | output  |
      |  ! A  ! B ! C !   |  a |      ! A  ! C !       |
         ! a ! true  ! 9 !            ! a ! 14 !
         ! e ! false ! 8 !
         ! a ! false ! 5 !
      |  ! A ! B ! C !    |  e |     ! A  ! C !      |
         ! a ! true  ! 9 !           ! e ! 8 !
         ! e ! false ! 8 !
         ! a ! false ! 5 !
```

I'm like 99% sure this is not going to be easy or ever supported in Gherkin syntax although happy to be proved wrong :-)
Instead then interested in any recommendations for how to approach this. The CSV example is one, but there could be other situations, e.g. a set of JSON or XML inputs for a particular computation.
The 2 options I have so far for describing the feature is

1. Continue using Scenarios and accept lots of duplication
2. I suppose the scenario outline examples could refer to external test resources by file name or similar. Could work but then the feature file doesn't really encapsulate expectations

Answer (score 0):

No this isn't possible.

The purpose of Cucumber is to support Behavior Driven Development. So it is assumed scenarios are shared with people. So readability should be emphasized.

And sometimes this can mean making your own DSL. For example the [cucumber-expressions module uses test cases written in yaml](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-expressions/blob/main/testdata/cucumber-expression/matching/matches-single-quoted-empty-string-as-empty-string-along-with-other-strings.yaml).

```yaml
---
expression: three {string} and {string} mice
text: three '' and 'handsome' mice
expected_args:
- ''
- handsome
```

These are executed as JUnit 5 tests:

```java
    private static List<Path> acceptance_tests_pass() throws IOException {
        List<Path> paths = new ArrayList<>();
        newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("..", "testdata", "cucumber-expression", "matching")).forEach(paths::add);
        paths.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
        return paths;
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource
    void acceptance_tests_pass(@ConvertWith(Converter.class) Expectation expectation) {
        if (expectation.exception == null) {
            CucumberExpression expression = new CucumberExpression(expectation.expression, parameterTypeRegistry);
            List<Argument<?>> match = expression.match(expectation.text);
            List<?> values = match == null ? null : match.stream()
                    .map(Argument::getValue)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            assertThat(values, CustomMatchers.equalOrCloseTo(expectation.expected_args));
        } else {
            Executable executable = () -> {
                CucumberExpression expression = new CucumberExpression(expectation.expression, parameterTypeRegistry);
                expression.match(expectation.text);
            };
            CucumberExpressionException exception = assertThrows(CucumberExpressionException.class, executable);
            assertThat(exception.getMessage(), equalTo(expectation.exception));
        }
    }
```

You can do the same thing and share those files instead or in addition to your feature files. Just don't list the external files in your feature file. That would be a pointless layer of indirection.